# How to add missing timeseries data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I've below Python3 pandas dataframe.

```
             dateTime              t        price     timestamp
0    2020-07-22 22:41:00+05:30  22:41:00  3136.0000  1595524260
1    2020-07-22 22:42:00+05:30  22:42:00  3132.0000  1595524320
2    2020-07-22 22:44:00+05:30  22:44:00  3134.0000  1595524440
3    2020-07-22 22:45:00+05:30  22:45:00  3130.0000  1595524500
4    2020-07-22 22:47:00+05:30  22:47:00  3122.0000  1595524620
5    2020-07-22 22:50:00+05:30  22:50:00  3118.0000  1595524800
6    2020-07-23 22:41:00+05:30  22:41:00  3136.0000  1595524260
7    2020-07-23 22:43:00+05:30  22:43:00  3133.0000  1595524380
8    2020-07-23 22:46:00+05:30  22:46:00  3129.0000  1595524560
9    2020-07-23 22:48:00+05:30  22:48:00  3124.0000  1595524680
10   2020-07-23 22:49:00+05:30  22:49:00  3123.0000  1595524740
11   2020-07-23 22:50:00+05:30  22:50:00  3118.0000  1595524800
```

Here, we can see that for everyday between time 22:41:00 to 22:50:00, few timeseries data is missing. I want missing data to be recalculated by taking price data from its previous / above row. The output should be as mentioned below.

```
             dateTime              t        price     timestamp
0    2020-07-22 22:41:00+05:30  22:41:00  3136.0000  1595524260
1    2020-07-22 22:42:00+05:30  22:42:00  3132.0000  1595524320
2    2020-07-22 22:43:00+05:30  22:43:00  3132.0000  1595524380
3    2020-07-22 22:44:00+05:30  22:44:00  3134.0000  1595524440
4    2020-07-22 22:45:00+05:30  22:45:00  3130.0000  1595524500
5    2020-07-22 22:46:00+05:30  22:46:00  3130.0000  1595524560
6    2020-07-22 22:47:00+05:30  22:47:00  3122.0000  1595524620
7    2020-07-22 22:48:00+05:30  22:48:00  3122.0000  1595524680
8    2020-07-22 22:49:00+05:30  22:49:00  3122.0000  1595524740
9    2020-07-22 22:50:00+05:30  22:50:00  3118.0000  1595524800
10   2020-07-23 22:41:00+05:30  22:41:00  3136.0000  1595524260
11   2020-07-23 22:42:00+05:30  22:42:00  3136.0000  1595524320
12   2020-07-23 22:43:00+05:30  22:43:00  3133.0000  1595524380
13   2020-07-23 22:44:00+05:30  22:44:00  3133.0000  1595524440
14   2020-07-23 22:45:00+05:30  22:45:00  3133.0000  1595524500
15   2020-07-23 22:46:00+05:30  22:46:00  3129.0000  1595524560
16   2020-07-23 22:47:00+05:30  22:47:00  3129.0000  1595524620
17   2020-07-23 22:48:00+05:30  22:48:00  3124.0000  1595524680
18   2020-07-23 22:49:00+05:30  22:49:00  3123.0000  1595524740
19   2020-07-23 22:50:00+05:30  22:50:00  3118.0000  1595524800
```

I'm not getting any idea to get this done. How can I write the Python3 code?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your dataframe `df`.

0. Import pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

1. Set the date as an index

```
df = df.set_index('dateTime')
```

2. Resample and forward fill

```
df=df.resample(`1 min').last().ffill()
```

3. Recompute the time column (I assume it is of type Timedelta):

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['t'] = df.dateTime - pd.to_datetime(df.dateTime.dt.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have the same range of minutes for each day and always have the first and last minutes filled, you could groupby date, resample each group and fill the nulls by appropriate logic for each column. here goes:

```
df['date'] = df.dateTime.dt.date

def group_action(df0):
    # resample
    df0 = df0.set_index(df0['dateTime'])
    df0 = df0.resample('1 min').first()
    df0['dateTime'] = df0.index
    df0.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    # fill the gaps
    df0['price'] = df0['price'].fillna(method='ffill')
    df0['timestamp'] = range(df0['timestamp'].iloc[0].astype('int'),\
                             df0['timestamp'].iloc[-1].astype('int')+60, 60)
    df0['t'] = df0['dateTime'].dt.time
    return df0

df.groupby('date').apply(group_action).reset_index(drop=True).drop('date', axis=1)
```